# Появление модального окна в зависимости от наличия в textarea слов how и help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Собственно, вся суть вопроса отражена в заголовке: имеется текстовое поле (textarea), которое будет полем для ввода комментариев. Есть кнопка, которая отправляет данные формы на серв.

Но нужно сделать так, чтобы при наличии в текстовом поле фразы, содержащих слов "how" & "help", появлялось модальное окно - не знаю, как этого добиться. Проблема еще и в том, что при нажатии на эту кнопку страница сразу обновляется. (Здесь в редакторе такой проблемы нет, но на [кодпене](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/EKNNBe) и странице в целом, она имеется). Кто знает, как решить проблему, прошу помочь.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
    $('.login-modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.comment-form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.comment-field {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 6px 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Georgia';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #222;
}
.comment-field:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.leave-comment-block {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
.leave-comment {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    width: 140px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #191919;
    line-height: 25px;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .15s;
    -o-transition: all .15s;
    transition: all .15s;
}
.leave-comment:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.leave-comment:active {
    opacity: .8;
}
.leave-comment:focus {
    outline: none;
}


/* Модальное окно */
.login-modal-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 5;
}

.login-modal-wrapper.open {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}

.login-modal-window {
    width: 320px;
    height: 370px;
    display: block;
    margin: 50% 0 0 -160px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.login-modal-wrapper.open .login-modal-window {
    margin-top: -185px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.btn-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; right: 10px;
    background:#ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    width:27px;
    height:26px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.btn-close::before, .btn-close::after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    content:'';
    width:13px;
    height:3px;
    display:block;
    background:#000;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-close::before{
    margin: 2px -3px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(50deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(50deg);
    transform:rotate(50deg);
}
.btn-close::after{
    margin: 2px -3px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-50deg);
    transform:rotate(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment-form" action="" method="get">
  <textarea class="comment-field"></textarea>
  <div class="leave-comment-block">
    <button class="leave-comment trigger" type="submit">Leave your comment</button>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="login-modal-wrapper">
  <div class="login-modal-window">
    <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял что у вас оператор `и` или `или` тут  "how" & "help", но если что меняется пара символов в `if()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(event) {
    if ($('.comment-field').val().toLowerCase().indexOf('how') != -1 ||
        $('.comment-field').val().toLowerCase().indexOf('help') != -1) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.login-modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.comment-form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.comment-field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 6px 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #222;
}
.comment-field:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.leave-comment-block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.leave-comment {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #a7a7a7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #191919;
  line-height: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s;
  -moz-transition: all .15s;
  -ms-transition: all .15s;
  -o-transition: all .15s;
  transition: all .15s;
}
.leave-comment:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.leave-comment:active {
  opacity: .8;
}
.leave-comment:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* Модальное окно */

.login-modal-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}
.login-modal-wrapper.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.login-modal-window {
  width: 320px;
  height: 370px;
  display: block;
  margin: 50% 0 0 -160px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.login-modal-wrapper.open .login-modal-window {
  margin-top: -185px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  width: 27px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.btn-close::before,
.btn-close::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  content: '';
  width: 13px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-close::before {
  margin: 2px -3px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(50deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(50deg);
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.btn-close::after {
  margin: 2px -3px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment-form" action="" method="get">
  <textarea class="comment-field"></textarea>
  <div class="leave-comment-block">
    <button class="leave-comment trigger" type="submit">Leave your comment</button>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="login-modal-wrapper">
  <div class="login-modal-window">
    <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Модальное окно должно появляться при наличии любого из этих слов, амперсанд использовал без задней мысли) Ваш скрипт почему-то не вызывает модалку, если эти слова есть в textarea..

Comment: @Игорь оператор ИЛИ сменил. Скрипт работает.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!